# Replace XML values with a .txt list

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, replace, kml

my coding skills are fairly weak so I apologize in advance if this is a fairly obvious question. 1) I have some XML code involving US Census Blocks. The code contains 45,000 elements named "Block 4004", "Block 2032", etc. Here is the specific code: https://data.cityofchicago.org/Facilities-Geographic-Boundaries/Boundaries-Census-Blocks-2010-KML/d4ha-f9xm. 2) I extracted with TextCrawler from this XML code a corresponding .txt list of actual block IDs "170314004", "170302032", etc. stored underneath each of these 45,000 elements. I simply need to replace the "Block 4004" with the "170314004" (while keeping the original "170314004" in the XML code undistrubed). What is the simplest way to accomplish this? Will I need to use some other programming tool (beside TextCrawler) or is there something else I can download to do it? Or will I need to do this in C or something?

Again, to be clear:

XML code has these elements:
Name - Block 4004
Name - Block 2032
Name - Block ...
txt file has these 1-to-1 corresponding elements (their ordering chronologically matches the XML code, because they were extracted from it):
1703140004
1703020322
17000...
And want the XML to display:
Name - Block 170004004
Name - Block 170002032
Name - Block ...

I can't simply insert the 17000 part in front because it uniquely varies by block and there are multiple Block 4004s and so on...

Please advise, thank you very much!

Comment: I don't know anything about TextCrawler, but since you're a "weak" programmer - are you familiar with MS Excel? You could do some string manipulation using that.

Comment: I've definitely spent my fair share of time using Excel but again my use of that is somewhat limited as well - I've used pivot tables and so forth, but if you're talking about VBA or something I'd probably need to study up. Would you suggest opening the XML file in Excel somehow?

Comment: Can you post a short example of what you have?

Comment: <name>Block 1031</name> ... this appears repeatedly in my XML file. Underneath that more data is contained, this ... <td>GEOID10</td> <td>170319800001031</td> and this arrangement happens about 45,000 times. I want to replace the name with the GEOID, but it's not a simple insert because the names repeat and all the GEOIDs are unique...

Answer (score 1):

Refer to this about opening XML documents in Excel: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/viewing-an-xml-file-in-excel-HA001034645.aspx ...and then you can simply write formulas to add/replace strings in a new column.

If you need to replace or create strings, you can write formulas using `CONCAT` and `MID`. There are loads of examples out there if you Google them.

Comment: Man I almost had success with this! I used Excel and made the appropriate edits to the names rather easily, but when I went to save it as an XML file it kept saying the same thing: "xml maps in this workbook are not exportable".

Comment: Maybe this will guide you on how to do that? http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/export-xml-data-HP010206401.aspx

Comment: Unfortunately I'm finding the Excel route difficult beacuse my "Map is not exportable because it contains the following: Lists of lists, Denormalized data, and A mapped element's relationship with other elements cannot be preserved". And because I didn't create the XML code I feel like I'd be pretty hard-pressed to figure out the solution to these challenges given my limited skills. Just to humor me are there any routes that might be advisable? Could I copy and paste the text into some other tool and develop somekind of algorithm to make the replacements?

Comment: That file is pretty big! It looks like a bunch of little HTML pages rather than a true XML dataset. Message me after you get the file and maybe I can help more.